# Conditionally emitting a method with TypeWriter

Tags: c#, typescript, typewriter

I'm using [TypeWriter](https://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/index.html) to generate TypeScript classes from my C# models.  It works great.  The following is my *existing* template in its entirety, which works fine:

```
${
    using Typewriter.Extensions.Types;

    Template(Settings settings)
    {
        settings.IncludeProject("ProjectName.Api");
        settings.OutputFilenameFactory = file => 
        {
            return file.Name.Replace("Dto.cs", ".ts");
        };
    }

    string DtoName(Class t) { return t.Name.Replace("Dto", ""); }
    string MapTypeName(Property p) { return MapTypeName(p.Type); }

    string MapTypeName(Type t)
    {
        var typeArguments = t.TypeArguments.ToList();

        if (typeArguments.Count == 1 && t.IsEnumerable)
        {
            return $"{MapTypeName(typeArguments[0])}[]";
        }

        if (typeArguments.Count == 2 && t.Name == $"KeyValuePair<{typeArguments[0]}, {typeArguments[1]}>")
        {
            return $"{{ key: {typeArguments[0]}; value: {typeArguments[1]}}}";
        }

        return t.Name.Replace("Dto", "");
    }
}

module CompanyName.Models.Api {
    $Classes(ProjectName.Api.Models.*Dto)[
    export class $DtoName {
        $Properties[
        public $name: $MapTypeName = $Type[$Default];]
    }]
}
```

I want to conditionally add a method to this template for a specific type.  I thought something like this would work:

```
module CompanyName.Models.Api {
    $Classes(ProjectName.Api.Models.*Dto)[
    export class $DtoName {
        $Properties[
        public $name: $MapTypeName = $Type[$Default];]

        ${
            if ($name == "ADto") 
            {
                // I want to emit this code:
                //    public getStatistic(appType: string, status: string): number {
                //        const retval = _.find(this.data, { appType: appType, status: status });
                //        return retval ? retval.count : 0;
                //    }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

But it doesn't like this syntax, and I get 5 Typewriter errors, including  "unexpected token" and "invalid token".  I attempted a variation of this:

```
module CompanyName.Models.Api {
    $Classes(ProjectName.Api.Models.*Dto)[
    export class $DtoName {
        $Properties[
        public $name: $MapTypeName = $Type[$Default];]

        $if ($name == "ADto") 
        {
            // I want to emit this code:
            //    public getStatistic(appType: string, status: string): number {
            //        const retval = _.find(this.data, { appType: appType, status: status });
            //        return retval ? retval.count : 0;
            //    }
        }
    }]
}
```

But Typewriter emits the entire `$if { ... }` block, which isn't exactly what I want.

Must I create a second template specifically for this class, or can I do this with the conditional?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, based on [this Github issue comment](https://github.com/frhagn/Typewriter/issues/96#issuecomment-195478370)

In the main body, above the template, add this helper function:

```
bool IsStatisticsClass(Class c)
{
    return c.Name == "ADto";
}
```

This gives us some kind of wrapper (I'm not sure what the correct terminology is).  We can use `$IsStatisticsClass[ ... ]` to conditionally add code.  The template itself becomes:

```
module CompanyName.Models.Api {
    $Classes(ProjectName.Api.Models.*Dto)[
    export class $DtoName {
        $Properties[
        public $name: $MapTypeName = $Type[$Default];]
        $IsStatisticsClass[            
        // This code is now emitted for a single class:
        //    public getStatistic(appType: string, status: string): number {
        //        const retval = _.find(this.data, { appType: appType, status: status });
        //        return retval ? retval.count : 0;
        //    }]
    }]
}
```

For the sake of consistency with my question, I've left the emitted TypeScript code commented out.